# installation problem in ROS

Tags: rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

﻿i tried to install ros in ubuntu 10.04 lucid but when i gave command i got following error:

sudo apt-get install ros-electric-desktop-full

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
ros-electric-desktop-full: Depends: ros-electric-slam-gmapping (= 1.2.5-s1326424166~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-electric-perception-pcl (= 1.0.2-s1323553637~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-electric-simulator-gazebo (= 1.4.10-s1326937730~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-electric-navigation (= 1.6.5-s1323562415~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages

what should I do?

When I tried to install from the source for the setup command :

“sudo apt-get install build-essential python-yaml cmake subversion wget python-setuptools mercurial git-core”

I got the following error:

Errors were encountered while processing:

/var/cache/apt/archives/xz-utils_4.999.9beta+20091116-1_i386.deb

/var/cache/apt/archives/patch_2.6-2ubuntu1_i386.deb

/var/cache/apt/archives/dpkg-dev_1.15.5.6ubuntu4.5_all.deb

/var/cache/apt/archives/build-essential_11.4build1_i386.deb

/var/cache/apt/archives/dkms_2.1.1.2-2ubuntu1_all.deb

/var/cache/apt/archives/fakeroot_1.14.4-1ubuntu1_i386.deb

/var/cache/apt/archives/fglrx_2%3a8.723.1-0ubuntu5_i386.deb

/var/cache/apt/archives/fglrx-amdcccle_2%3a8.723.1-0ubuntu5_i386.deb

/var/cache/apt/archives/libboost1.42-dev_1.42.0-3~lucid1_i386.deb

/var/cache/apt/archives/libboost-dev_1.42.0.1~lucid1_i386.deb

/var/cache/apt/archives/libboost-serialization1.42-dev_1.42.0-3~lucid1_i386.deb

/var/cache/apt/archives/libboost-date-time1.42-dev_1.42.0-3~lucid1_i386.deb

/var/cache/apt/archives/libboost-date-time-dev_1.42.0.1~lucid1_i386.deb

/var/cache/apt/archives/libboost-system1.42-dev_1.42.0-3~lucid1_i386.deb

/var/cache/apt/archives/libboost-filesystem1.4E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12913/installation-problem-in-ros/) by [nandhini](https://answers.ros.org/users/1736/nandhini/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2012-02-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Based on your own answer and the fact that you cannot install the prerequisites you appear to have conflicts in your PPA sources which conflict with standard Ubuntu packages.  You'll have to resolve that before continuing.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nandhini](https://answers.ros.org/users/1736/nandhini/) on 2012-02-09**:
can u say how to resolve it?